# My code is working, but I'm trying to understand something regarding constructors.

Tags: java, constructor

I've created an new class that can create rational numbers and can calculate with rational numbers. My code is working fine, I was trying a lot of things and it works, however I don't really understand what is happening in my constructors. I've looked into the java tutorial on Oracle, but didn't find my answer.

My questions is about my temporary argument in my constructor, (Rational B2)

```
public Rational count(Rational b2) {                //ok
    int newNumerator = (this.Numerator * b2.denominator) + (this.denominator *    b2.Numerator); 
    int newDenominator = this.denominator * b2.denominator; 
    Rational r = new Rational(newNumerator, newDenominator);
    return r;
```

My questions is: What is happing with b2? What is the function of b2 and where is it stored?

Hopefully someone can explain it to me so I have a better understanding about my code :)

Comment: _public Rational count(Rational b2)_ this is not a constructor :)

Comment: Trust me. `public Rational count(Rational b2)`  is a method

Comment: You should clarify your question... "What is the function of b2" does not make much sense, for instance

Comment: This is a valid method. The only thing here would be to set Rational as a data type such as int or whatever

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not a constructor. `b2` is just used to get its `denominator` and `numerator` in order to create a new `Rational` instance.

The method could have been:

```
public Rational count(int otherNumerator, int otherDenominator) {                //ok
    int newNumerator = (this.Numerator * otherDenominator) 
                        + (this.denominator * otherNumerator); 
    int newDenominator = this.denominator * otherDenominator; 
    Rational r = new Rational(newNumerator, newDenominator);
    return r; 
}
```